# "IS NOT" syntax error in Java / SQLite application

Tags: java, sqlite, sqlexception

I'm working on an Java application with SQLite database. I have to execute this query :

```
select * from service 
where (tache IS NOT 'I') 
AND (idequiv IS null OR idequiv = '' OR idequiv<=0) 
union 
select * from service where (idequiv IS NOT null) 
and (tache IS NOT 'I') 
group by num_service 
order by num_service;
```

This works well in SQLiteStudio, but in my application I got this exception :

```
 java.sql.SQLException: near "'I'": syntax error    at
 org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)     at
 org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)     at
 org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)     at
 org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:37)   at
 org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:231)    at
 org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:224)    at
 org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:213)
```

Any Idea why ? 
I'm desperate ..

Comment: @Mat all SQL databases implement `IS` and `IS NOT` exactly this way. This doesn't have anything to do with Java

Answer (score 2):

`IS NOT` and `IS` is used for NULL values. Use `<>` or `NOT a = b` for values.

```
SELECT * FROM service 
WHERE (NOT tache = 'I') 
AND (idequiv IS null OR idequiv = '' OR idequiv<=0) 
UNION
SELECT * FROM service 
WHERE (idequiv IS NOT null) 
AND (NOT tache = 'I') 
GROUP BY num_service 
ORDER BY num_service;
```

Comment: it doesn't seem here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html Is it a Java restriction?

Comment: That's strange. I just referred to standard SQL.

Comment: So SQLite isn't standard =D But maybe Java try to correct this??

Comment: I don't know enough about the java implementation to answer that, sorry.